# PHP change date format (date coming from MySQL's 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'

Tags: php, mysql, date

I tried a few things and so far and no success.

I want to make dates that are yyyy-mm-dd look like mm/dd/yyyy

Initial value example, taken from MySQL: 2015-08-21 14:46:00

Here's what I got:

```
foreach ($draftOrders as $key => $value) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($value['last_modified']);

    // this one works (leaving it unchanged)
    // however the slashes are not replacing the dash
    // $new_date_format = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $timestamp);

    // fails, date becomes 1970-01-01 12:00 am
    $new_date_format = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
    $draftOrders[$key]['last_modified'] = $new_date_format;
}
```

Comment: and this error is...? and if you want this format, there's no reason to post-process in php, you can select the format you want [directly from mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), saving you a bunch of wasted cpu cycles on strtotime()

Comment: what is the type that you want ? ?

Comment: Edited my Q. The errors were syntax errors, irrelevant.

Comment: What is the output of your code?

Comment: Do that in the database rather than in php - should be quicker

Comment: I want mm/dd/yyyy. The output is 1970-01-01 12:00 am. I wrote those as comments in my questions's code

Comment: thanks ill check how to do it from mysql

Answer (score 1):

To perform that sort of date formatting in mysql you might want to look at the following:-

```
select date_format(`date`,'%Y/%m/%e %H:%i:%s') from `table`
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am now trying to find out how to fit that in within a Laravel's Eloquent query. If anybody knows how please feel free to say it :-)

Comment: Glad it was helpful - sorry, can provide no info regarding Laravel... good luck

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 echo date('m/j/Y', strtotime('2015-08-21 14:46:00'));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php